# How to read whole file in one string

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to read json or xml file in pyspark.lf my file is split in multiple line in

```
rdd= sc.textFile(json or xml)
```

Input

```
{
" employees":
[
 {
 "firstName":"John",
 "lastName":"Doe" 
},
 { 
"firstName":"Anna"
  ]
}
```

Input is spread across multiple lines.

Expected Output `{"employees:[{"firstName:"John",......]}`

How to get the complete file in a single line using pyspark?

Comment: the whitespace doesn't matter, really, it's only there for display purposes. json with line breaks/indentation is still json...

Comment: How to append every think one single string

Comment: How to append think in one line(string)by removing whitespace

Comment: Do you want the entire RDD in one string or do you want you want everything of a single record together?

Comment: I want you want everything of a single record together

Comment: Does your input file contains more than one record?

Comment: Yes I have multiple line file I want merge to single line

Comment: Unclear why you'd want this if Spark has a builtin JSON parser

Answer (score 10):

There are 3 ways (I invented the 3rd one, the first two are standard built-in Spark functions), solutions here are in PySpark:

textFile, wholeTextFile, and a labeled textFile (key = file, value = 1 line from file. This is kind of a mix between the two given ways to parse files).

**1.) textFile**

input:
    `rdd = sc.textFile('/home/folder_with_text_files/input_file')`

output: array containing 1 line of file as each entry ie. [line1, line2, ...]

**2.) wholeTextFiles**

input:
    `rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles('/home/folder_with_text_files/*')`

output: array of tuples, first item is the "key" with the filepath, second item contains 1 file's entire contents ie.

[(u'file:/home/folder_with_text_files/', u'file1_contents'), (u'file:/home/folder_with_text_files/', file2_contents), ...]

**3.) "Labeled" textFile**

input:

```
import glob
from pyspark import SparkContext
SparkContext.stop(sc)
sc = SparkContext("local","example") # if running locally
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

for filename in glob.glob(Data_File + "/*"):
    Spark_Full += sc.textFile(filename).keyBy(lambda x: filename)
```

output: array with each entry containing a tuple using filename-as-key with value = each line of file. (Technically, using this method you can also use a different key besides the actual filepath name- perhaps a hashing representation to save on memory). ie.

```
[('/home/folder_with_text_files/file1.txt', 'file1_contents_line1'),
 ('/home/folder_with_text_files/file1.txt', 'file1_contents_line2'),
 ('/home/folder_with_text_files/file1.txt', 'file1_contents_line3'),
 ('/home/folder_with_text_files/file2.txt', 'file2_contents_line1'),
  ...]
```

---

You can also recombine either as a list of lines:

`Spark_Full.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1]))).collect()`

```
[('/home/folder_with_text_files/file1.txt', ['file1_contents_line1', 'file1_contents_line2','file1_contents_line3']),
 ('/home/folder_with_text_files/file2.txt', ['file2_contents_line1'])]
```

Or recombine entire files back to single strings (in this example the result is the same as what you get from wholeTextFiles, but with the string "file:" stripped from the filepathing.):

`Spark_Full.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], ' '.join(list(x[1])))).collect()`

Comment: Since you're joining lines, you should use `'\n'.join(list(x[1])`, but what is `Spark_Full`? A list?

Answer (score 7):

If your data is not formed on one line as `textFile` expects, then use `wholeTextFiles`.

This will give you the whole file so that you can parse it down into whatever format you would like.

Answer (score 7):

This is how you would do in scala

```
rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://nameservice1/user/me/test.txt")
rdd.collect.foreach(t=>println(t._2))
```

Answer (score 5):

### "How to read whole [HDFS] file in one string [in Spark, to use as sql]":

e.g.

```
// Put file to hdfs from edge-node's shell...

hdfs dfs -put <filename>

// Within spark-shell...

// 1. Load file as one string
val f = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs:///user/<username>/<filename>")
val hql = f.take(1)(0)._2

// 2. Use string as sql/hql
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val results = hiveContext.sql(hql)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python way

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://nameservice1/user/me/test.txt")
json = rdd.collect()[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-text.html, you can read with:

```
text_df = spark.read.text("your_path", wholetext=True)
text = text_df.first().value
```