# Read a textfile of fixed length with newline as one of attribute value into a JavaRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a textfile which is of width 100 byte. Following is the structure. I need to read the data in a JavaRDD.

```
RecType - String 1 Byte
Date    - String 8 byte
Productnumber - String 15 byte
TAG           - String 11 byte
Filler1       - String 1 byte
Contract      - String 11 byte
Code          - String 3 byte
Version       - String 3 byte
newline       - String 1 byte
FILENAME      -String  25 byte
Recnumber     - String  4 byte
```

Sample Data in a file

```
020190718000000000000001CHATHOLDER SUBCONTRACT1MNV3.0
LOGFILEGENAT07312019050AM00001020190718000000000000001CHATHOLDER SUBCONTRACT1MNV3.0
LOGFILEGENAT07312019050AM00002020190718000000000000001CHATHOLDER SUBCONTRACT1MNV3.0
LOGFILEGENAT07312019050AM00003020190718000000000000002CHATHOLDER SUBCONTRACT1MNV3.0
LOGFILEGENAT07312019051AM00004
```

If you notice Every record start in a line and ends up in the next line. From the very next byte next records starts. There are 4 records in the file starting with string 020190718.

Could you please help me how to read the records in a JavaRDD?

I was trying

```
JavaRDD1 = SparkUtils.getSession().read().textFile(filepath)
         javaRDD()
         map(x -> {return FunctiontoParse(x);});
```

But it was only considering one line at a time instead of reading whole record.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to [see this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445263/how-to-read-whole-file-in-one-string)  Using `wholeTextFile()` will work if everything is good with being a String.  If you want it to stay binary, then you need to read it as binary. I've used [`JavaSparkContext.binaryFiles(filepath,numPartitions)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html) instead.  This reads the entire file as bytes and lets you parse it however you want.

```
JavaSparkContext jsc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate());
//from here each file gets on record in the resulting RDD.  Each Record is a filename, file_contents pair.  Each record has the contents of an entire file.
JavaPairRDD<String, PortableDataStream> rawBinaryInputFiles = jsc.binaryFiles(HDFSinputFolder,numPartitions);
//now to use your function to parse each file.  Keep in mind, each record has the contents of an entire file, 
//you will need to parse out each record.  But since it's fixed width by bytes, it should be pretty simple.  
//Create a custom wrapper object to hold the values and populate.

JavaRDD<YourCustomWrapperObject> records =  rawBinaryInputFiles.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String,PortableDataStream>, YourCustomWrapperObject>() {

    @Override
    public Iterator<YourCustomWrapperObject> call(Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream> t) throws Exception {
        List<YourCustomWrapperObject> results = new ArrayList<YourCustomWrapperObject>();
        byte[] bytes = t._2().toArray(); //convert PortableDataStream to byte array.
        //best option here IMO is to create a wrapper object, populate it from the byte array and return it
        YourCustomWrapperObject obj = new YourCustomWrapperObject();
        //populate....
        results.add(obj);
        return results;
    }
});
```

Comment: I am very new to this. Could you please provide some sample code.

Comment: rawBinaryInputFiles was not able to parse the data and not returning as expected. I used readwholefiles to separate key values. Then wrote a simple java program to separate the records and bringing one record in a line.

Answer (score 0):

A version running in scala:

```scala
def chunkFile(file: String) : List[(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)] = {

    import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

    val rowSize = 84
    val list = new ListBuffer[(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)]
    for(i <- 0 to (file.length / rowSize)-1){
        val row = file.substring(i * rowSize, (i+ 1) * rowSize)
        val items = (row.substring(0, 1),row.substring(1, 9),row.substring(9, 24),row.substring(24, 35), row.substring(35, 36),row.substring(36, 47), row.substring(47, 50),row.substring(50, 53),row.substring(54, 55),row.substring(55, 80),row.substring(80, 84))
        list += items
    }

    list.toList
}

val file = sc.wholeTextFiles("C:/git/files/newline-as-data.txt")
chunkFile(file.collect.map(f => f._2).head).toDF.show
```

altough to be honest i would pre-process the file and strip out the newline then you can treat it as a normal load rather than something like this that will need to read the entire file into memory