# Can someone explain how spark rdd.map decides to read lines insted of words from a textfile?

Tags: python, apache-spark, functional-programming

I have the current code

```
lines = sc.textFile("file:///SparkCourse/ml-100k/u.data")
ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split()[2])
result = ratings.countByValue()
```

According to this, 'x' ends up representing a line in text-file:
Excerpt from text-file:

```
196 242 3   881250949
186 302 3   891717742
22  377 1   878887116
244 51  2   880606923
166 346 1   886397596
```

Why/how does map split this up per line and returns a line as 'x'?

- Contrary to returning each individual literal based on whitepace?
- Does *map* allways look for lineshift? Can we specify any other distinction?

Answer (score 0):

This is what sc.textFile does: reads file into RDD of Strings:

```
 SparkContext.textFile(name, minPartitions=None, use_unicode=True)[source]

    Read a text file from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI, and return it as an RDD of Strings
```

See [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.textFile.html)

And `RDD.map` retuns new RDD applying a function to each element of RDD. in this case element is a whole line from the file.

and split() splits delimited string and returns array

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense to have a look what you have stored in `lines`. There you can see that that the dataframe contains the file as a dataframe of rows.

`lines.map()` then "iterates" through the rows/lines as you already mentioned.

You can read the whole file like this `rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("file:///SparkCourse/ml-100k/u.data")`

It will return a tuple of the key (file paht) and a value (content of the file)

[How to read whole file in one string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445263/how-to-read-whole-file-in-one-string)

Edit:
See Doc for explanation
[https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/programming-guide.html#external-datasets:~:text=SparkContext.wholeTextFiles%20lets%20you%20read%20a%20directory%20containing%20multiple%20small%20text%20files%2C%20and%20returns%20each%20of%20them%20as%20(filename%2C%20content)%20pairs.%20This%20is%20in%20contrast%20with%20textFile%2C%20which%20would%20return%20one%20record%20per%20line%20in%20each%20file](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/programming-guide.html#external-datasets:%7E:text=SparkContext.wholeTextFiles%20lets%20you%20read%20a%20directory%20containing%20multiple%20small%20text%20files%2C%20and%20returns%20each%20of%20them%20as%20(filename%2C%20content)%20pairs.%20This%20is%20in%20contrast%20with%20textFile%2C%20which%20would%20return%20one%20record%20per%20line%20in%20each%20file).